# How to add types checker for the Jest in the TypeScript app?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, jestjs

I need to add some type checker to the Jest. It must look somehow like `expect(someVar).toBeType('string')` and `expect(someVar).toBeType(['string', 'object'])`.

I tried to add some checker-helper, but it looks a little bit ugly.

```js
const toBeType = (arg:any, type:string) => {
    const argType = typeof arg;

    if (argType !== type)
        throw new Error(`Expected '${type}' but got '${argType}' for the '${arg}'.`);
};
```

I want to add similar functionality to the `jest` namespace to have ability to call type checker like `expect(someVar).toBeType('boolean')`.

Comment: The compiler (assuming your tests are in typescript too and run by ts-jest) will enforce type safety, no need to add assertions.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this problem this way. To add functionality to the Jest we should use `expect.extend({...})`. So, to add `toBeType` method to the Jest we should write this code to some `setupTests.js` file:

```
// setupTests.js

expect.extend({
    /**
     * @param {*} received
     * @param {string|string[]} arg
     * @return {{pass:boolean,message:(function():string)}}
     */
    toBeType(received, arg) {
        const isCorrectType = arg => {
            const receivedType = typeof received;

            const checkForSingle = arg => {
                const type = receivedType === 'object'
                    ? Array.isArray(received)
                        ? 'array'
                        : receivedType
                    : receivedType;

                return type === arg;
            };

            const checkForArr = arg => {
                const reducer = (prev, curr) => prev
                    || isCorrectType(curr).isCorrect;

                return arg.reduce(reducer, false);
            };

            return {
                receivedType,
                isCorrect: Array.isArray(arg)
                    ? checkForArr(arg)
                    : checkForSingle(arg)
            };
        };

        const {isCorrect, receivedType} = isCorrectType(arg);

        return {
            pass: isCorrect,
            message: () => {
                const toBe = Array.isArray(arg)
                    ? arg.join(`' or '`)
                    : arg;

                return `Expected '${received}' of '${receivedType}' type to be of '${toBe}' type(s)`;
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Don't forget to add `setupTests.js` to the `jest.config.js` file as follows:

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    ...your_configurations...
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setupTests.js'],
};
```

Also we have to extend `global.d.ts` file to say interpreter we have `toBeType` method at the `extend` namespace (it is required if only you are using TypeScript). Here is code we have to add to `global.d.ts`:

```js
// global.d.ts

declare namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
        toBeType(type:string|string[]);
    }
}
```

This code says: get `jest` namespace and extend `Matchers<R>` interface with the `toBeType` method. (You can look at `Matchers<R>` interface implementation at the [`@types/jest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jest) node module.)